# How to count on chain transactions for an address between blocks in solidity

Tags: transactions, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

Is there a function in solidity to get a count of specific address transactions made on a chain between specific blocks? Let say it's a BSC or ETH chain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BSC and Ethereum smart contracts only have access to the current state - not to historical states at previous blocks.

Also, there's currently no EVM opcode (hence no Solidity function) to look up the amount of transactions by an address.

---

If your use case allows to use off-chain tools, one of the ways to get the count of outgoing transactions by an address is the `web3` method [getTransactionCount()](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.5.2/web3-eth.html#gettransactioncount) (wrapper for the [eth_getTransactionCount](https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API#eth_gettransactioncount) RPC method). If your provider is an archive node (and allows requesting historic states), you can get the transaction count at two specific blocks and compare the values, which will give you the count difference between the specified blocks.

Comment: This is what I needed, thank you very much!